# SQL - Join with multiple condition

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to join my `users` table with my `jobs` table based on a mapping table `users_jobs`:

Here is what the `users` table looks like:

```
 users
|--------|------------------|
|  id    |        name      |    
|--------|----------------- |
|   1    |  Ozzy Osbourne   |
|   2    |  Lemmy Kilmister |
|   3    | Ronnie James Dio |
|   4    |    Jimmy Page    |
|---------------------------|
```

`jobs` table looks like this:

```
    |--------|-----------------|
    |  id    |      title      |    
    |--------|-----------------|
    |   1    |  Singer         |
    |   2    |  Guitar Player  |
    |--------------------------|
```

And `users_jobs` table looks like this:

```
  |--------|-------------|-------------|---------------|-------------|
  |  id    |  user_id    |   job_id    |  column3      |    column4  |
  |--------|-------------|-------------|---------------|-------------|
  |   1    |      1      |     1       |     0         |      1      |
  |   2    |      2      |     1       |     1         |      0      |
  |   3    |      3      |     1       |     0         |      1      |
  |   4    |      4      |     2       |     1         |      0      |
  |----------------------|-------------|---------------|-------------|
```

For example, let's say the ozzy does a query. 
Here is what should expect:

```
|--------|------------------|------------|--------- |
|  id    |        name      |   column3  | column4  |
|--------|----------------- |------------|----------|
|   1    |  Ozzy Osbourne   |     0      |    1     |
|   2    |  Lemmy Kilmister |     1      |    0     |
|   3    | Ronnie James Dio |     0      |    1     |
|---------------------------|------------|----------|
```

Basically, he can only see the job in which he is registered (role) and the users included.

I tried to do this:

```
SELECT u1.*, uj1.colum3, uj1.column4 
FROM users AS u1 
  JOIN users_jobs AS uj1 ON uj1.user_id = 1 
  JOIN jobs AS j1 ON j1.id = up1.job_id
WHERE uj1.job_id = 1
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. 
Using @stackFan approach adding an `EXISTS` clause to make sure that the user is in.

```
SELECT u.id, u.column3 , u.column4 
FROM users u 
 INNER JOIN user_jobs uj on u.id = uj.user_id 
 INNER JOIN jobs j on j.id = uj.job_id 
WHERE uj.job_id = <job-ID>
AND 
EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM users_jobs AS uj
       WHERE uj.job_id = <job-ID>
       AND uj.user_id = <user-ID>
       );
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need `INNER JOIN` Try this :

```
select u.id, u.column3 , u.column4 from users u 
inner join user_jobs uj on u.id=uj.user_id 
inner join jobs j on j.id=uj.job_id 
where uj.job_id=1;
```

If you need by certain `user_id`

```
select u.id, u.column3 , u.column4 from users u 
inner join user_jobs uj on u.id=uj.user_id 
inner join jobs j on j.id=uj.job_id 
where uj.job_id=1
and u.id=1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But following the example of the question, even if "ozzy" is not registered in the job table, following this example it would be able to view the remaining users, which is not an option.

Comment: Can you put a SQLFiddle for your example? We could look further into that more easily that way.

Comment: Sorry for expressing myself wrong, english is not my native language. I would like that when performing the query it would only return if the user were also in the table. For example: If "ozzy" was not in the jobs table, when it performed the query, it would return null.

Comment: No problem. But looking at your `user_jobs` table, it has `user_id` =1 and `jobs_id`= 1 which means Ozzy has job of singer.

Comment: Yes, in that scenario. But if Ozzy had no relation to the jobs table, the return should be null. Following your answer, even if he isn't relating to the jobs table he could see the remaining users, in this case Lemmy and Dio.

Comment: then just provide the `user_id` of the person you are looking as well.

Comment: If I provide the user_id, I will only retrieve the provided user_id. I need the list of users, of course if the user that requested is also on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try `LEFT JOIN`.  It will display all users, whether they have job or not.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, uj.colum3, uj.column4 
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN users_jobs uj ON uj.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON j.id = uj.job_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the desired one is that it's only possible to see other users if the user who made the query was also inserted in the table.